# How to translate DbEntityEntry's OriginalValues to strongly typed and detached object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation

I'm currently testing and revising my api service. The main Update function calls validation and event handlers but relies heavily on DbEntityEntry. The problem with DbEntityEntry, or more precisely its OriginalValues property, is that it won't throw exceptions or alert the compiler when accessing an entity's non-existent property. The search is on for a more robust class to translate OriginalValues to, but I've come up empty.

Here is what I started with:

```
public override Item Update(Item revisedItem, DbContext context) {
    DbEntityEntry entry = context.Entry<Item>(revisedItem);
    DbPropertyValues originalValues = entry.OriginalValues;
    ...
    validateType(revisedItem.Type, entry.OriginalValues.GetValue<Nullable<decimal>>("Tipe"));  //GetValue won't catch the misspelling of "Type"
    ...
    return revisedItem; 
}
```

This is bothersome because I suddenly have to test to make sure that OriginalValues returns what I expect, to safeguard against typos. I'm more than willing to inform DbPropertyValues that the data it carries is that of an Item. I would simply use OriginalValues.ToObject() and place it on an entity, but having two entities of the same EntityKey complicates things past my familiarity with Entity tracking.

What is an alternative to using OriginalValues that doesn't use reflection? It should also be able to co-exist alongside its modified Entity.

Thanks for your time and patience, as I am working on rebuilding my understanding of strongly typed languages.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to quickly continue work so I've come up with a decent, but less than ideal solution. I've created a class which is essentially a wrapper for DbPropertyValues, called DbEntityPropertyValues which takes a type argument. When GetValue is called, it uses reflection (bleh) to check if the EntityType has the given property. Unlike DbPropertyValues, it will throw an error if the property does not exist. This is not very useful during runtime, but it will weed out problems more easily during testing.

The way constructors have been designed gets around DbPropertyValue's mocking insufficiency. There are two constructors for DbEntityPropertyValues, one takes a single DbPropertyValue, and one takes an entity. DbProperyValue will be used during normal operation, entities will be used during mocking. And here's the code.

```
public class DbEntityPropertyValues<EntityType> where EntityType : MyEntity {

    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> entityKeyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public DbEntityPropertyValues (DbPropertyValues dbPropertyValues) {
        IEnumerable<string> dbPropertyNames = dbPropertyValues.PropertyNames;

        foreach(var prop in dbPropertyNames) {
            entityKeyValuePairs.Add(prop, dbPropertyValues.GetValue<Object>(prop));
        }
    }

    //Intended only for testing.
    //A detached entity gets passed in instead of DbPropertyValues which can't be mocked.
    public DbEntityPropertyValues (CompanyEntity entity) {
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> entityProperties = typeof(EntityType).GetProperties().AsEnumerable();

        foreach (var prop in entityProperties) {
            entityKeyValuePairs.Add(prop.Name, entity.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(entity, null));
        }
    }

    public T GetValue<T> (string propertyName) {
        if (!typeof(T).Equals(typeof(EntityType).GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType)) {
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("{0} of type {1} does not exist on entity {2}", propertyName, typeof(T), typeof(EntityType)));
        }

        return (T)entityKeyValuePairs[propertyName];
    }
}
```

Criticism and suggestions are welcome.